# Passing malloc struct array through a function

Tags: c

I'm creating a game that creates a struct of creatures and struct of rooms using malloc. In my first function, i create the amount of rooms that the user inputs. I then ask the user for the status of the room either 1 2 or 3 then ask the cords for north south east and west. That is all for this function. Everything is fine up to this point. Then when i create my creatures, I initialize them through input via user. I ask the user for the creature type which can only be 0 1 or 2, then ask for the location of the creature and the location will be associated with the room number. So if creature location is 1 then its in room 1. but for some reason it changes my cords in my rooms in the creature function. Literally changes them out of no where.

Example, I enter for 4 rooms, first room 0,1,2,3,4 then second room 3,1,2,4,3 then same for room 3 and four. For now, the cords dont matter but my problem is that through the creature function, it changes my cords for some reason. Can someone please help me. I know this is a lot of code but I'm out of ideas

```
struct room
{
   int roomNum;
   int creaturesTotal;
   int roomStatus;
   int roomTotal;
   int north;
   int south;
   int east;
   int west;
};

struct Creatures
{
  int creatureType;
  int creatureNum;
  int location;
};

 int main()
{
int numberofrooms = 0;
int numberofcreatures = 0;


/*ask user for rooms and creatures*/
printf("How many rooms? Max 10 rooms: ");
scanf("%d",&numberofrooms);
/*make sure its under 10 rooms*/
while(numberofrooms > 10)
{
    printf("\nToo many rooms!\n");
    printf("How many rooms? Max 10 rooms: ");
    scanf("%d",&numberofrooms);
}

printf("How many creatures? Max 100 creatures: ");
scanf("%d",&numberofcreatures);

while(numberofcreatures > 100)
{
    printf("\nToo many creatures! MAX 100 creatures please!\n");
    printf("How many creatures? Max 100 creatures: ");
    scanf("%d",&numberofcreatures);
}

  struct Creatures*AllCreatures = malloc(numberofcreatures * sizeof(numberofcreatures));
  struct room *AllRooms = malloc(numberofrooms * sizeof(numberofrooms));

  createRooms(numberofrooms, AllRooms);
  createCreatures(numberofcreatures,AllCreatures,AllRooms);
 }

void createCreatures(int numberofcreatures, struct Creatures* AllCreatures,struct room* AllRooms)
{
  int location;

  int counter = 0;
  int PC = 0;

//ask the user for creatures and check the inputs
for(int i=0; i < numberofcreatures; i++)
{
    int creatureType;

        printf("\nType of Creature, Location: ");
        scanf("%d%d",&creatureType,&location);

        //if room is full
        while(AllRooms[location].roomTotal == 10)
        {
            printf("\nRoom is already full!\n");
            printf("\nType of Creature, Location: ");
            scanf("%d%d",&creatureType,&location);

            //make sure isnt invalid creature num in nested while loop
            while(creatureType < 0 || creatureType > 2)
            {
                printf("\ninvalid creature type\n");
                printf("\nType of Creature, Location: ");
                scanf("%d%d",&creatureType,&location);
            }
        }

        //if room isnt full but invalid creature type
        while(creatureType < 0 || creatureType > 2)
        {
            printf("\ninvalid creature type\n");
            printf("\nType of Creature, Location: ");
            scanf("%d%d",&creatureType,&location);
        }

         if(creatureType == 0)
         {
             PC++;
             while(PC > 1)
            {
                 printf("\nThere is already a PC player, enter again");
                 printf("\nType of Creature, Location: ");
                 scanf("%d%d",&creatureType,&location);
                 if(creatureType == 1 || creatureType == 2)
                 {
                     PC--;
                 }
            }
         }


    //print out the creatures with the room numbers
    AllCreatures[i].location = location;
    AllCreatures[i].creatureType = creatureType;
    AllCreatures[i].creatureNum = counter;

    //AllRooms[AllCreatures[i].location].roomTotal = AllRooms[AllCreatures[i].location].roomTotal + 1;
    counter++;
}

for(int i=0; i < numberofcreatures; i++)
{
    printf("\n Creature num %d, type %d, location %d\n",AllCreatures[i].creatureNum, AllCreatures[i].creatureType,AllCreatures[i].location);
}
}

//create all rooms
void createRooms(int numberofrooms,struct room* AllRooms)
{
   int counter = 0;
   int status;
   int north;
   int south;
   int east;
   int west;

//ask the user for the cords
for(int i =0; i < numberofrooms;i++)
{
    printf("Room Number %d state north south east west: ",counter);
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&status,&north,&south,&east,&west);
    AllRooms[i].roomStatus = status;
    AllRooms[i].north = north;
    AllRooms[i].south = south;
    AllRooms[i].east = east;
    AllRooms[i].west = west;
    AllRooms[i].roomNum = counter;
    AllRooms[i].roomTotal = 0;
    counter++;
}

//print out the cords
for(int i =0; i < numberofrooms;i++)
{
    printf("\n%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",AllRooms[i].roomStatus,AllRooms[i].north,AllRooms[i].south,AllRooms[i].east,AllRooms[i].west);
}
}
```

Comment: Your mallocs have the wrong number of bytes; Try this pattern:  `T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);`

Comment: Also you call undeclared functions in `main`  , the function declaration must appear earlier than the call. The compiler should warn about this -- adjust your settings if you dont' see a warning

Comment: Im sorry. i forgot to add the declaration in my question. But thank you so much, it seems that i did have the wrong number of bytes. I would of never guessed that was wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Malloc Error**
Not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but you aren't allocating enough space.

**Current:**
struct Creatures*AllCreatures = malloc(numberofcreatures * sizeof(numberofcreatures));
  struct room *AllRooms = malloc(numberofrooms * sizeof(numberofrooms));

**Change to:**
struct Creatures*AllCreatures = malloc(numberofcreatures * sizeof(struct Creatures));
  struct room *AllRooms = malloc(numberofrooms * sizeof(struct room));

This could be the problem, but if it doesn't fix it comment on this and I will red more to see if I can solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it seems like changing my mallocs to this format worked. T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);

Comment: I guess i didnt have the right number of bytes and someone that was changing my numbers